# Creating a clean TIN interpolation without "Bleeding" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation

If you assume I know little to nothing about QGIS 3.10, but have been attempting with some success to create fictional world maps with it, and that I have very limited (OpenScript and Excel) programming skill, perhaps the imprecise technical nature of my question will make more sense!

I am creating Raster files to serve as DEM files.

My process is to create a a set of polygons (within a multi-polygon shapefile layer) for elevation contours.

I have tried starting the coastline contour as elevation 0, elevation 1 and elevation 10

I have used elevation (contour) intervals of 100

I then use Vector/Geometry Tool/ Extract Vertices and get a series of points along each polygon perimeter.

I use the Processing Toolbox / Vector Geometry/ Add Geometry Attributes tool to create x,y,z coordinates for each point

I have then gone into the attribute table, selected all of the points, used the multi edit tool and set zcoord = to elevation

I then have either created contours from the data, or just used the points themselves with similar results, and completed a TIN interpolation.

The raster files are sufficient to create a decent 3-D map, but the triangulation plays havoc with my coastline (the 0,1 or 10 elevation contour) as shown in the photo.  [image]

You can see the triangles departing the coastline, which produces a raster that doesn't really show the coast at all.   I have added a second photo to demonstrate and you can see the triangles jutting off the coastline in the raster file

[image]

I am certainly committing some error in this process and wondering if anyone can direct me to a tutorial or provide some suggestions for how to create a more precise coastline.

I have not yet attempted creating a -100 contour around the island and then a 0 elevation coastline.

Here it is after implementing Gabriel De Luca's suggestion about adding points where sections of the polygons were excessively long unbroken lines.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In some sectors of the coastline, the vertices are far apart from each other, so the triangulation finds triangles that cross over the coastline.

[Densify by count](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisdensifygeometries) the coastline. Add only one point for each segment. Extract the vertices and interpolate again.  If it is not enough, densify it again by adding one more point per segment.

---

In *TIN interpolation*, you can show triangulation instead of interpolation, as a previous step, to see where interpolation is taking place.

[image: 1]

Comment: Thank you Gabriel!  That makes total sense looking at the map - those errant triangles occur where I had long stretches of unbroken segments in the polygon edge.  I will add points and try it again.  I will now also do more research on interpolation and triangulation.

Comment: @ReallyNewUser You are welcome! Automated triangulation algorithms follow the [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) method, considering all the points belonging to a plane. Elevations are then interpolated following each side of the generated triangles. The addition of break and structure lines should avoid unwanted triangulations, but I am not totally satisfied with the way these restrictions are taken into account, at least in QGIS *TIN interpolation* algorithm.

Comment: it worked very nicely!  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Before you go into this work, check if data isnt avalible already. You can get 90 m DTM for the whole world here: http://www.webgis.com/srtm3.html.
Also 30m is avalible for some reagions, as far as i know for US and Europe..

Basically your 0 m contour is the coastline. You can convert it to polygon and clip raster with it. Think this is the most reliable way of getting exact coastline you wanted.
If i was doing this task, workflow would be:

-draw polygon for each contour, layer would include column "z" for hight of each contour

-extract vertices (each point should already have height attribute from step 1)
-TIN interpolation (in SAGA Tin plate spline you can select attribute column, dont need actual point  z coordinate)

-Clip raster by mask layer (select coastline, so 0 m contour and use it to clip "bleeding" Dem with it.)

Comment: Cliping the result does not solve the topographic error caused by interpolating a point in the territory with a point on the coast on the other side of a water mirror.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mat.  As I am not using real world data, the first part won't apply.   I will test out the other settings you mention - I have found that the stretch and clip setting has given me the best results but I will try the combinations you suggest.